# Use of US Census data to plot house value range

Tags: united-states, census, choropleth, normalize

The house value data from the US Census Bureau is provided as a table differentiating areas into census tracts. My understanding is that they categorize each tract into quantities of homes fitting within a certain value range and provide an estimate of the total number of homes within each tract. For example, tract 123 has an estimate of 200 total houses and 5 houses ranging from 10k to 15k, 6 houses ranging from 15k to 20k, and so on.

I am wanting to derive a map illustrating the tracts fitting a value range. For example, a chloropleth map displaying the tract differences among houses valued within the range of 10k to 15k. **In order to do this, wouldn't I first need to take the number of houses within a particular range and divide it by the total number of houses estimated for the same tract?** It seems simply plotting the number of homes within a certain value range for a particular tract would mean I was plotting unnormalized values and thus an inaccurate portrayal.

I wanted to make sure I was understanding what the raw census data represented and how to properly use this data.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using COUNTY PARCEL DATA if it is available. It should contain land, house and total market values by individual parcel. That way you can create a chloropleth map and use that market value data and categorize that anyway you want.